# What does FOTA mean

Tags: ota-update

I just got an over-the-air update from HTC for my Wildfire S  for the "FOTA Client" (or something like this, can't see it anymore after the update and can't find any logfiles in the FileManager or elsewhere) and somne related component also with FOTA in the name.

Googling FOTA only yields blog posts and news about "phone X getting FOTA update" with none of these explaining what it means. Searching here yields zero results...

So, what does FOTA mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

FOTA -  Firmware Over-the-Air

This is the update sent to the OS via your service provider(for 3G/GPRS/EDGE..) or Wifi.

It will download an image of the new firmware from the server and install it after you accept.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOTA_%28technology%29),

> FOTA is an acronym for Firmware Over-the-Air. It is used for upgrades to mobile phones and PDAs.